# Using previous version of gcc for mex in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gcc, mex

I want to use gcc version 4.9 with Matlab.  I have gcc-4.9 installed, but my attempts to use it with Matlab have been thwarted.

```
Warning: You are using gcc version '5.4.0'. The version of gcc is not supported. 
The version currently supported with MEX is '4.9.x'. For a list of currently 
supported compilers see:
```

**My Attempts:**

1) mex -setup, and mex -setup C++

Does not display options to choose from, just shows

```
MEX configured to use 'gcc' for C language compilation.
```

And I don't know what to do with that.

2) https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html

copyfile(fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','examples','refbook','timestwo.c'),'.','f')
mex -v GCC='/usr/bin/gcc-4.7' timestwo.c

This does not apply to me, since I'm not trying to compile a single file.

3) Editing mexopts.sh both in "MatlabRoot/bin/" and ~/.matlab/R2016b

(restarted Matlab and got the same error)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It's important to note that that is *not* an error, just a warning.

Comment: Thank you @Suever, I'm going to change that.

Comment: Did you try running the mex file? If it issues this warning, it will *still* create a mex file that should run just fine.

Comment: I did try.  I'm attempting to install xfemm, and when I use a function in the xfemm package I get the error

 "'/home/peter/vac-matlab/xfemm_linux64/mfemm/xfemm_mex_files_for_glnxa64/fpproc_interface_mex.mexa64':
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not
found (required by/home/peter/vac-matlab/xfemm_linux64/mfemm/xfemm_mex_files_for_glnxa64/fpproc_interface_mex.mexa64)."

I figured this may be a result of the not using gcc-4.9, so I wanted to attack the 'root' of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

to change gcc and g++ version used in MATLAB (I'm using R2017b on Ubuntu 16.04), first of all, install gcc-4.9 and g++-4.9 using

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

to change version of gcc, run following command:

```
sudo gedit ~/.matlab/R2017b/mex_C_glnxa64.xml
```

and replace **Location="$GCC"** with **Location="/usr/bin/gcc-4.9"**

to change version of g++, run following command:

```
sudo gedit /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/mexopts/g++_glnxa64.xml
```

and replace **Location="$G++"** with **Location="/usr/bin/g++-4.9"**

To verify that changes is done correctly, run following command in MATLAB Command Windows:

> for gcc

```
myCCompiler = mex.getCompilerConfigurations('C','Selected')
```

> for g++

```
myCCompiler = mex.getCompilerConfigurations('C++','Selected')
```

I hope, it helps.